# Unable to find the "extensions" portion of my php.ini file, in apache 2.0, where is it?

Tags: php, ubuntu, apache2, gd

I'm trying to add support for the GD extension on my Ubuntu, Apache 2, php box. However my php.ini file does not seem to be the same as most versions of the INI file and it appears that their are no ;extensions comments or a place holder for them. Where did this move to? Is their a new location or new method for adding extensions?

I'm at a loss, I only found 2 php.ini files. One for Apache 2 and one for the command line interface.

Ultimately I'm asking this question because the normal fix for the error **Undefined offset: 1 in [...]images.php on line 50 Fatal error: Call to undefined function imagecreatefrompng() in [...]functions.php on line 309**  does not work.

Comment: Meh, missed that in the body :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Most distros, Ubuntu included, generally keep PHP extensions' .ini files in a seperate sub-dir from the main .ini file.

You should have a `/etc/php5` directory, with `conf.d` sub-dir for the main configuration, and `apache` and `cli` sub-dirs for the individual versions.

However, Ubuntu has a php5-gd package which will install the extension automatically, so hacking up the .ini files should NOT be necessary, unless you have to compile a specific version of GD yourself.

Comment: In webmin the file or folder conf.d is not accessible see image: http://i.imgur.com/VTnzm.png

Comment: You could try using the `dl()` function load it dynamically within your script, but that may not be permitted by your host. You may have to call them to get GD enabled.

Comment: I'm hosting the server... I have the physical box. I could try a terminal session to get access to that file.

Comment: I modified the file but did not find the extension file, so I created gd.ini and added extension=gd.so but I still get the error in my question. Any suggestions? Do I have the module gdu.so installed?

Comment: Generally on ubuntu you'd only have to install the php-gd5 package and restart Apache for it to work.

Comment: I can't locate that package? Does it come under another name?

Comment: oops, sorry, brainfart. Should be php5-gd. It's here for 10.10: http://packages.ubuntu.com/maverick/php/php5-gd

Answer (score 1):

If there are no extensions in your php.ini, then that's fine. Just because the comments are missing in your `.ini` file doesn't mean that the "section" has moved; they're just comments!

If you want one, create it.

It starts with the text `extension=`.

Comment: Are you sure... the PHP ini file doesn't seem to be the same one I'm used to. It looks different.

Comment: @Justin: Please wait while I go invent telepathy. I will then be able to comment on the precise contents of your file.

Comment: Ok I found the section but, I include extensions=gd.so and I'm still getting the error "undefined function imagecreatefrompng()".

Answer (score 1):

The gd extension configuration file is in `/etc/php5/conf.d/gd.ini`: unless I'm wrong by default all the files in the /etc/php5/conf.d folder are automatically included in the PHP runtime.

Answer (score 0):

I'm using Ubuntu 14.04 LTS and have the package installed, but Drupal was not detecting it. I looked through the folders and found NOTHING regarding `gd save` and empty section in the ini files. The error message went away when I manually created the file for the extension in `/etc/php5/mods-available`. I copied one of the files and changed it to load gd.so, like this:

```
; configuration for php gd module

; priority=20

extension=gd.so
```

If you don't have the file either, try that, restart Apache2 and see if it helps.