# where should i add the extension=mcrypt.so in php.ini?

Tags: php, mcrypt

I am a newbie to php, and during an installation of a server I have to add the extension extension=mcrypt.so in php.ini file where I stuck with the following issues
1) I donno where exactly the above mentioned line should be added in the php.ini file.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Unable to find the "extensions" portion of my php.ini file, in apache 2.0, where is it?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5939149/unable-to-find-the-extensions-portion-of-my-php-ini-file-in-apache-2-0-where)

Comment: Ubuntu 14.04: `sudo gedit /etc/php5/apache2/php.ini`

Comment: It is best not to use mcrypt, it is abandonware, has not been updated in years and does not support standard PKCS#7 (née PKCS#5) padding, only non-standard null padding that can't even be used with binary data. Instead consider using [defuse](https://github.com/defuse/php-encryption), it is being maintained and is correct.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You will see a group of `Dynamic Extensions.` like this:

```
;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;
; Dynamic Extensions ;
;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;

; If you wish to have an extension loaded automatically, use the following
; syntax:
;
;extension=modulename.extension
```

add your extension below this without `;`

Comment: yes done it and one more thing to go
1) Could not save the file “/etc/php5/apache2/php.ini”.You do not have the permissions necessary to save the file. Please check that you typed the location correctly and try again

what should be the workaround for the above error?

Comment: Restart server or anything else?

Comment: I am unable to save it? By the way do I need to save that??

Comment: You have to open this file a root/administrator, which OS are you using?

Comment: Use this command: `sudo gedit /path/to/php.ini`. the php.ini will be open in gedit (default editor) and you will be able to save the changes.

Comment: that is where i did all the above changes which u have suggested previously in this thread  :)

Answer (score 1):

Add this line to all other extensions:

```
;extension=some.so
extension=thing.so
extension=mcrypt.so
```

Also, don't forget to reboot web server after that to make it work.

Comment: My question is where to add it, I am unable to find(where exactly the line to be added) there is lot of stuff in php.ini

Comment: Just find section with a lof of commented and uncommented extensions and add your line there.